# Работа с файлом формата *.rsp

Tags: windows-10

Есть программа secret net, в ходе установки можно создать конфигурационный файл установки программы. Создаётся файл формата *.rsp. В документации сказано, что это можно только через сервер безопасности, но мне кажется что можно сделать установку автономной с помощью этого файл.
Ну или хотя бы как работать с файлами такого формата, никогда не видел и в интернете не очень много об этом сказано

```
[core]
Action=install
[Console]
Action=install
[local]
Action=install
DC=1
ERASER=1
EXEQUOTA=1
FDC=1
MC=1
[pc]
Action=install
[Disk]
Action=install
CRCONT=1
FDE=1
[COMMON]
Action=install
Installdir=C:\Program files
server=
Source=путь до программы установки
Division=
SysName=
Workplace=
Id=
LicenseFilePath=
Locale=ru
[ta]
Action=install
TA_Firewall=1
TA_IDS=0
TA_IPSEC=0
[continent]
Action=none
[softpspt]
Action=install
[te]
Action=none
[Antivirus]
Action=none
[Sandbox]
Action=none
[patches]
count=0
```